# New page appears indented (moved to the right)

Tags: spacing, indentation, page

When I begin a new page it seems like page x is normal but the next page x+1 is completely indented, the next page x+2 normal and the next x+3 indented, I don't find the way to solve this

[image]

My code is here [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/1919637832mpfqdjqdrtvw)

I've tried `\,` `\noindent`, `\newpage`, `\begin{flushleft}...`, `\hspace`, etc. but it doesn't help.

Comment: Probably you are using the class option `twoside`. Delete it, or equivalently, use `oneside`.

Comment: note that if you print the document on to paper, using both sides, then normally you want this setting, If the document is mainly for pdf reading on screen then "twosided" print settings are usually not wanted.

Comment: unrelated but those `\\ ` in your document must be making latex complain about badness 10000 (the maximum level of hbadness for the output) you should never have `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph and never have consecutive `\\ `